# How can I select a specific column from each row in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame in this format:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3   10  11  12
4   13  14  15
```

and an array like this, with column names:

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b']
```

and I’m hoping to extract an array of data, one value from each row. The array of column names specifies which column I want from each row. Here, the result would be:

```
[1, 4, 8, 12, 14]
```

Is this possible as a single command with Pandas, or do I need to iterate? I tried using indexing

```
i = pd.Index(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b'])
i.choose(df)
```

but I got a segfault, which I couldn’t diagnose because the documentation is lacking.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use [`lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html), e.g.

```
>>> i = pd.Series(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b'])
>>> df.lookup(i.index, i.values)
array([ 1,  4,  8, 12, 14])
```

where `i.index` could be different from `range(len(i))` if you wanted.

Comment: That’s fantastic, thank you! Is it also possible to _assign_ to those indexes?

Comment: You *can* assign, but ONLY when the frame is a single dtype (as it is now). ``df.unstack().loc[zip(i.values,i.index)] = [1,2,3,4,5]``. And you must match the length on both sides (you can also select using this syntax); see this issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7138

Comment: If you want to add the index, make a series: ``pd.Series(df.lookup(i.index, i.values), index=i.index)``

Comment: In pandas 1.2.0, the lookup function is deprecated and it is recommended to use either .loc or .melt (see : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)

Answer (score 8):

For large datasets, you can use indexing on the base numpy data, if you're prepared to transform your column names into a numerical index (simple in this case):

```
df.values[arange(5),[0,0,1,2,1]]

out: array([ 1,  4,  8, 12, 14])
```

This will be much more efficient that list comprehensions, or other explicit iterations.

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer. Since [`pd.lookup()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)  is deprecated now and the `melt()` solution can get you into memory issues for large data sets

Answer (score 2):

As MorningGlory stated in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833130/how-can-i-select-a-specific-column-from-each-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe#comment116086004_24833589), `lookup` has been deprecated in version `1.2.0`.

The documentation states that the same can be achieved using `melt` and `loc` but I didn't think it was very obvious so here it goes.

First, use `melt` to create a look-up `DataFrame`:

```
i = pd.Series(["a", "a", "b", "c", "b"], name="col")
melted = pd.melt(
    pd.concat([i, df], axis=1),
    id_vars="col",
    value_vars=df.columns,
    ignore_index=False,
)

  col variable  value
0   a        a      1
1   a        a      4
2   b        a      7
3   c        a     10
4   b        a     13
0   a        b      2
1   a        b      5
2   b        b      8
3   c        b     11
4   b        b     14
0   a        c      3
1   a        c      6
2   b        c      9
3   c        c     12
4   b        c     15
```

Then, use `loc` to only get relevant values:

```
result = melted.loc[melted["col"] == melted["variable"], "value"]

0     1
1     4
2     8
4    14
3    12
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Finally - if needed - to get the same index order as before:

```
result.loc[df.index]

0     1
1     4
2     8
3    12
4    14
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Pandas also provides a different solution in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels) using `factorize` and `numpy` indexing:

```
df = pd.concat([i, df], axis=1)
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['col'])
df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]

[ 1  4  8 12 14]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always use list comprehension:

```
[df.loc[idx, col] for idx, col in enumerate(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b'])]
```

Comment: This is not vectorized, you can do anything with for loops

Comment: This would work, however, it would be very slow compared with accessing NumPy arrays as @mdurant 's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24833522/4245771