# Create 'children' rows in panda dataframe, based on unique values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, explode

Take the example:

```
pd.DataFrame(
            index=["r1", "r2"],
            columns=["c1","c2","c3", "group_by"],
            data=[
                ["v1",[{"x_title":"xt1","x_label":"xl1","y_title":"yt1","y_label":"yl1"},
                        {"x_title":"xt1","x_label":"xl1","y_title":"yt2","y_label":"yl2"}, 
                        {"x_title":"xt2","x_label":"xl2","y_title":"yt3","y_label":"yl3"}],
                        "v3","x"],
                ["v1",[{"x_title":"xt1","x_label":"xl1","y_title":"yt1","y_label":"yl1"},
                        {"x_title":"xt2","x_label":"xl2","y_title":"yt2","y_label":"yl2"}, 
                        {"x_title":"xt3","x_label":"xl3","y_title":"yt3","y_label":"yl3"}],
                        "v3","y"],
            ]
        )
```

Which produces a dataframe like:

```
    c1                                                 c2  c3 group_by
r1  v1  [{"x_title": "xt1", "x_label": "xl1", "y_title...  v3        x
r2  v1  [{"x_title": "xt1", "x_label": "xl1", "y_title...  v3        y
```

The main point of conversation will be c2, which is a list of dictionaries. I would like to "pull out" each unique value for the k,v pair where k ~= f"{parent.group_by}_title". So if `group_by` on the row == `x`, each unique `x_title` will have a "child" row generated that keeps all the remaining values.

The end dataframe will hopefully look similar to:

```
pd.DataFrame(
            index=["r1","r2","r1","r1","r2","r2","r2"],
            columns=["group","orig_name","c2","c3", "type"],
            data=[
                [None,"v1",None,"v3","parent"],
                [None,"v1",None,"v3","parent"],
                ["xt1","v1",[{"y_title":"yt1","y_label":"yl1"},{"y_title":"yt2","y_label":"yl2"}],"v3","child"],
                ["xt2","v1",[{"y_title":"yt3","y_label":"yl3"}],"v3","child"],
                ["yt1","v1",[{"x_title":"xt1","x_label":"xl1"}],"v3","child"],
                ["yt1","v1",[{"x_title":"xt2","x_label":"xl2"}],"v3","child"],
                ["yt1","v1",[{"x_title":"xt3","x_label":"xl3"}],"v3","child"],
            ]
        )
```

or like:

```
   group orig_name                                                 c2  c3  type
r1  None        v1                                               None  v3  r1  parent
r2  None        v1                                               None  v3  r2  parent
r1   xt1        v1  [{"y_title": "yt1", "y_label": "yl1"}, {"y_tit...  v3  r1   child
r1   xt2        v1             [{"y_title": "yt3", "y_label": "yl3"}]  v3  r1   child
r2   yt1        v1             [{"x_title": "xt1", "x_label": "xl1"}]  v3  r2   child
r2   yt1        v1             [{"x_title": "xt2", "x_label": "xl2"}]  v3  r2   child
r2   yt1        v1             [{"x_title": "xt3", "x_label": "xl3"}]  v3  r2   child
```

I'm able to do this "manually" but iterating through each row and going from there. But I would like to have a more "pandas" answer if possible. I've dabbled in `~apply(lambda ~`, `explode`, using a `def children(row)` function put into a `~apply(lambda ~`, and a few other methods. They are didn't quite align to what I'm interested in, and none are quite close enough to provide details.

I'm sure (as I always do) I'm somehow overthinking/looking a simple solution, just not aware of a function that will help, or just no using one of my tries correctly.

Hoping someone could explain a better way of doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more direct way of approaching this but to me  it looks like you could:

- turn the nested list/dicts from `c2` into rows/columns
- perform parent/child grouping
- rebuild the `c2` column

**Step 1:**

You can `.explode("c2")` then `pd.json_normalize`

```
df = df.explode("c2")
c2 = pd.json_normalize(df["c2"]).set_index(df.index)
df[c2.columns] = c2
df["c2"] = None
```

I've assigned `c2` to `None` here just to simplify the output.

```
    c1    c2  c3 group_by x_title x_label y_title y_label
r1  v1  None  v3        x     xt1     xl1     yt1     yl1
r1  v1  None  v3        x     xt1     xl1     yt2     yl2
r1  v1  None  v3        x     xt2     xl2     yt3     yl3
r2  v1  None  v3        y     xt1     xl1     yt1     yl1
r2  v1  None  v3        y     xt2     xl2     yt2     yl2
r2  v1  None  v3        y     xt3     xl3     yt3     yl3
```

**Step 2:**

[`.columns.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) can map column names to indexes.

```
>>> df["group_by"] + "_title"
r1    x_title
r1    x_title
r1    x_title
r2    y_title
r2    y_title
r2    y_title
Name: group_by, dtype: object
```

```
>>> df.columns.get_indexer(df["group_by"] + "_title")
array([4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6])
```

The indexes allow you to extract from a different column on a per-row basis: [How can I select a specific column from each row in a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833130/how-can-i-select-a-specific-column-from-each-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

This can be used to create group/key/value columns:

```
df["key_name"]   = df["group_by"].map({"x": "y", "y": "x"}) + "_title"
df["value_name"] = df["group_by"].map({"x": "y", "y": "x"}) + "_label"

rows = range(len(df.index))

df["group"] = df.values[rows, df.columns.get_indexer(df["group_by"] + "_title")]
df["key"]   = df.values[rows, df.columns.get_indexer(df["key_name"])]
df["value"] = df.values[rows, df.columns.get_indexer(df["value_name"])]
```

```
    c1    c2  c3 group_by x_title x_label y_title y_label key_name value_name group  key value
r1  v1  None  v3        x     xt1     xl1     yt1     yl1  y_title    y_label   xt1  yt1   yl1
r1  v1  None  v3        x     xt1     xl1     yt2     yl2  y_title    y_label   xt1  yt2   yl2
r1  v1  None  v3        x     xt2     xl2     yt3     yl3  y_title    y_label   xt2  yt3   yl3
r2  v1  None  v3        y     xt1     xl1     yt1     yl1  x_title    x_label   yt1  xt1   xl1
r2  v1  None  v3        y     xt2     xl2     yt2     yl2  x_title    x_label   yt2  xt2   xl2
r2  v1  None  v3        y     xt3     xl3     yt3     yl3  x_title    x_label   yt3  xt3   xl3
```

**Step 3:**

The parent rows:

```
>>> df.groupby(df.index).first()
    c1    c2  c3 group_by x_title x_label y_title y_label key_name value_name group  key value
r1  v1  None  v3        x     xt1     xl1     yt1     yl1  y_title    y_label   xt1  yt1   yl1
r2  v1  None  v3        y     xt1     xl1     yt1     yl1  x_title    x_label   yt1  xt1   xl1
```

The child rows:

I think there may be a smarter way to turn the columns back into dicts - but for now:

```
df["c2"] = [ 
   { row[f"{col}_name"]: row[col] for col in ("key", "value") }   
   for row in df[["key_name", "value_name", "key", "value"]].reset_index(drop=True).to_dict("records")
]
```

```
>>> df["c2"]
r1    {'y_title': 'yt1', 'y_label': 'yl1'}
r1    {'y_title': 'yt2', 'y_label': 'yl2'}
r1    {'y_title': 'yt3', 'y_label': 'yl3'}
r2    {'x_title': 'xt1', 'x_label': 'xl1'}
r2    {'x_title': 'xt2', 'x_label': 'xl2'}
r2    {'x_title': 'xt3', 'x_label': 'xl3'}
```

You can then `.groupby("group")` and `.agg()`

For `.agg()` you want to use `list` for the `c2` column and `first` for every other column.

One way to write this is to map all column names to the default action you want and merge a dict of "overrides":

```
>>> columns = "a", "b", "c"
>>> dict.fromkeys(columns, "first") 
{'a': 'first', 'b': 'first', 'c': 'first'}
>>> dict.fromkeys(columns, "first") | dict(c="list")
{'a': 'first', 'b': 'first', 'c': 'list'}
```

On the dataframe:

```
>>> df.reset_index().groupby("group").agg(dict.fromkeys(df.columns, "first") | dict(c2=list))
       c1                                                 c2  c3 group_by x_title x_label y_title y_label group key_name value_name  key value
group                                                                                                                                         
xt1    v1  [{'y_title': 'yt1', 'y_label': 'yl1'}, {'y_tit...  v3        x     xt1     xl1     yt1     yl1   xt1  y_title    y_label  yt1   yl1
xt2    v1             [{'y_title': 'yt3', 'y_label': 'yl3'}]  v3        x     xt2     xl2     yt3     yl3   xt2  y_title    y_label  yt3   yl3
yt1    v1             [{'x_title': 'xt1', 'x_label': 'xl1'}]  v3        y     xt1     xl1     yt1     yl1   yt1  x_title    x_label  xt1   xl1
yt2    v1             [{'x_title': 'xt2', 'x_label': 'xl2'}]  v3        y     xt2     xl2     yt2     yl2   yt2  x_title    x_label  xt2   xl2
yt3    v1             [{'x_title': 'xt3', 'x_label': 'xl3'}]  v3        y     xt3     xl3     yt3     yl3   yt3  x_title    x_label  xt3   xl3
```

You could then remove any columns that are no longer needed - add a parent/child identifer column to the parent/child rows and `.concat` them.